# server side node.js request couldnt connect to host

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, server

I try using server side node.js and write a simple -general- javascript code for http request

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("Hello World!");
    response.close();
}).listen(1337);

sys.puts("Server running 8080");
```

when i execute on server it's work and give me out put "Server running 8080" string.

But couldnt connect to host when i check on browser.
(i try this http://myserverip:1337)
I open 1337 port but still same

Answer (score 0):

Same thing on Linux. Check your network connectivity. If you are on Amazon, check your security groups. It has be something that is blocking that port.